# OpenGL - Linking two textures doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm trying to link both the depth texture and the color texture of an FBO to a GLSL Shader (version 4.0)

Problem is , only one links at the same time , Strange because other textures link together well (example : diffuse , normal and specular maps)

Here's my bind RT code :

```
void RenderTexture::BindRead(GLuint locationColor,GLuint locationDepth,unsigned int unit,unsigned int dUnit)
{
    colorUnit = unit;
    this->depthUnit = dUnit;
    assert(unit >= 0 && unit <= 31);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,m_rt);
    if (hasDepth)
    {
        assert(depthUnit >= 0 && depthUnit <= 31);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + dUnit);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,m_depth);
        glUniform1i(locationDepth,dUnit);
    }
    glUniform1i(locationColor,unit);
}
```

I don't really know what's wrong in here...

Comment: how do you know that BINDING the textures to the shader does not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: No , i don't get an error , both the sampler2Ds return the same value , (if i set depth first , then both of them will have the depth texture)

Comment: can you show the shader?

Comment: `#version 400
 layout(location=0) out vec3 FragColor;
 in vec2 UV;
 uniform sampler2D rt0;
 uniform sampler2D d0;

 void main() {
  vec3 tex = texture(rt0,UV).xyz;
  vec3 depth = texture(d0,UV).xyz;
  FragColor = tex + depth;
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally , i found a solution!** The problem was that i bound the program AFTER the values are set , it should be before , This also fixed many other bugs i was having.